# ASP.NET Web API - pass a complex type from javascript json

Tags: javascript, c#, json, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-ajax

I have an ASP.NET Web API that accepts a POST with a UserModel in it:

```
[HttpPost]
public object Post(UserModel userModel)
{
    // some logic here
}
```

The UserModel is a complex type that looks like this:

```
public class UserModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public AddressModel CurrentAddress { get; set; }
}
```

The `AddressModel` Model looks like this:

```
public class AddressModel
{
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public string Number { get; set; }
}
```

I'm trying to call this API from javascript and send a JSON object. This is the JSON object I'm sending:

```
var user = {
    Id: 1,
    FirstName: 'Hello',
    LastName: 'World',
    CurrentAddress: {
        Country: 'Israel',
        City: 'Tel Aviv',
        Street: 'Shalom',
        Number: '5'
    }
};
```

What I get in my Post method is a `UserModel` with the UserModel fields filled with the correct information, the CurrentAddrent address is initialized, but the values sent are not there. The values of the parent object (the `UserModel` object are ok).

What am I doing wrong here? how can you send a complex object to WebAPI Model?

Comment: It should not be rather `[FromBody] UserModel userModel`?

Comment: I'd definitely double check the JSON being sent up with a tool like Fiddler

Comment: Perhaps not related but your types don't really match: `FirstName` and `LastName` are `int`s, should be `string`s

Comment: Ran your example above, with types corrected for `FirstName` and `LastName` and returning `void` instead of `object` from the `Post` method, worked as expected on my machine.

Comment: @Christian you are right - I've written the code here as an example and copy & pasted without noticing. I will revise the post. thanks.

Comment: It's very simple object for JSON deserialization. As @Padraic suggested use Fiddler. I would start from sending JSON directly from Fiddler and only then checking what is sent from javascript.

Comment: @developer82 I've tried to send you json from postman, and everything works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

to receive complex data objects in MVC web API actions you have to add [FromBody] attribute to your POST arguments.

The [FromBody] tells the Web API to search for the parameter’s value in the body of a POST request.

```
 [HttpPost]
 public void Post([FromBody] UserModel userModel)
 {

 }
```

I've made a local test and I obtained the values.

I hope it helps!